# How to add a payment gateway with two different accounts?

Tags: commerce

I want to add two different accounts for a single gateway . Depending  upon `Product_id` or `product_sku` value it should use a corresponding account for payment.

How to do it? I have used the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

Comment: I don't believe I've seen any gateway to allow this. On the other hand, why don't just add two instances? But most modules probably don't support it yet.

Comment: how to add another instance ?  How to get out it ?

Comment: Hard to tell. My only experience is with PayU Poland which has an API totally independent and different from API of PayU India - not to mention other brands. Whatever I possibly could tell, would be next to useless to you :( That's why I posted general suggestion in comments, not an answer.

Comment: okay .Wish someone  have answer for this qustion

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question...

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple payment method rules for the same payment gateway and add conditions to them that check for the existence of particular products in the order's line items. How you do that is up to you and what your product catalog is like.

Comment: what would be the condition in RULE ???

Comment: I have find out the query string from url and then extract the "cid" from it then save it to an session variable as follows:  
    $query = parse_url($_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $q=$query['query'];
    $exp=explode('=',$q);
    $_SESSION['cid']= $exp[1] ;
Then i go to Payment Gateway Rule and add Condition "Execute php code" there I have put code as follows:
if($_SESSION['cid']=='TN201501HP')
{
 unset($_SESSION['cid']);
 return FALSE;
}
 
Remember Negate should remains unchecked.

Comment: `what would be the condition in RULE ???` well it depends, how many corresponding account payment are we talking about? 2 or 3? or lots?